# Changing the input after the first function - how to stop this?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to make two functions in the same script - but when i import them into my main script and run the first one first `finalGrade(grades)`, `grades` has changed with an extra column `'Final Grade'`. How do i prevent this?

In the first function i use another function I've made to return the DataSet with the final grade for each student as below:

```
# Made Andreas DÃ¸ssing Mortensen s184507 & Mads Westergaard s180799

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from roundGrade import roundGrade


def computeFinalGrades(grades):
    #making an array from dataFrame
    arr=grades.values
    #sorting and deleting the first two columns
    gradesarr=np.sort(np.delete(arr,(0,1),axis=1))
    #setting up a list for the final grades
    gradesInList=np.zeros(len(gradesarr))
    for i in range(len(gradesarr)):
        #if -3 is in a row, the final grade should be = -3
        if -3 in gradesarr[i]:

            gradesInList[i]= -3
        #if there is 2 or more grades in a row, execute the procedure below
        elif len(gradesarr[i])>=2:
            #Delete the smallest grade
            meangrade=np.delete(gradesarr,0,axis=1)
            #taking the mean of each row
            finalgrade = np.mean(meangrade[i])
            #making a list with all the final grades
            gradesInList[i] = roundGrade(finalgrade)

        # if there is only one value in the row, return that as the final grade 
        elif len(grades[i])==1: 
            gradesInList[i] = gradesarr
        #Setting up the dataFrame again
        df = pd.DataFrame(grades)
        #Adding final grades to DataFrame
        df['Final Grade']=gradesInList
        #Show all columns
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
        gradesFinal=df

    return gradesFinal
```

My functions for the plots looks like this:

```
#Importing add-ins
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#import pandas as pd

#importing function
from computeFinalGrades import computeFinalGrades



def finalGrade(grades):


    #Counting number of occurencies of each grade and set labels for x,y
    computeFinalGrades(grades)['Final Grade'].value_counts().sort_index().plot("bar",title="Final grades").set(xlabel='Grades',ylabel='Count')


    #show plot
    plt.show()

    return



def assignmentGrades(grades):

    #create an array with all grades
    array = grades.values
    #Sorting and deleting "Name" and "StudentID" from the array
    gradesarray = np.sort(np.delete(array,(0,1),axis=1))
    #making a for loop, to iterate trough array
    for i in range(len(gradesarray)):
        #Defining the length of the array to define max x-values
        num_ass = len(gradesarray[0])
        #Setting the x-axis values to correspond with number of assignments + a jiggler in the interval [-.1,.1] on both axis
        x = np.arange(1,num_ass+1) + np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1)

        y = gradesarray[i,:] + np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1)
        #Plotting the x,y "o" for creating scatterplot
        plt.plot(x, y,"o")

    #Drawing mean of grades as line
    meangrade = np.mean(gradesarray,0)
    #Plotting the mean grade as a line
    plt.plot(x,meangrade)
    #Set labels for x,y
    plt.xlabel('Assignments')
    plt.ylabel('Grades')
    #show plot
    plt.show()

    return
```

Hope you can guys can help with an easy fix, I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to talk you through how I found the solution to your problem:

- You stated the behaviour: `grades` changes after calling `assignmentGrades` and then has an additional column `Final Grade`.
- Since you're not directly changing `grades` in that method, you probably pass its reference to another variable and then change that. 
  You've done that twice,

  - once with `arr = grades.values` and
  - once with `df = pd.DataFrame(grades)`.
  - You then add the `Final Grade` column to `df`
- I get suspicious and figure out that the type of `grades` is probably a `pd.DataFrame` and that the constructor - when given a reference to another `pd.DataFrame` - does not make a copy. So in the end `df` is operating on the same object as `grades`. When you change one, you change the other.

To assert this, I wrote the following code

```py
a = pd.DataFrame({ "first": [1, 2], "second": [3, 4]})
b = pd.DataFrame(a)
# b = pd.DataFrame(a.copy()) # Fix

b['new'] = [5, 6]
print(a)
print(b)
```

Which indeed printed the changed `a` and `b`:

```
   first  second  new
0      1       3    5
1      2       4    6
   first  second  new
0      1       3    5
1      2       4    6
```

**To fix your code**, use a copy of `grades` (`grades.copy()`) when creating `df`.

**What could have helped you figure this is out** is a debugger which lets you step through your code and watch the current value of your variables. This way, you can see when `grades` change and then draw your conclusions.

---

I would also recommend renaming `df` to `gradesFinal` since `gradesFinal = df` does not do anything.